# Как правильно удалить объект из HashMap по истечении времени?

Tags: java, коллекции, telegram-bot, map, telegram

Есть реализация Telegram API на Java (бот на отдельном потоке). В `Map<Long, Order>` записываются данные заказа: улица, номер дома и т.д. Может быть такое, что нажали кнопочку заказа, ничего не ввели (или ввели часть) и забыли. Но объект-то остаётся в `Map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Пишете свою реализацию **Map** с этой функциональностью
2. Берете готовую реализацию [Cache](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) из [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)
3. Берете готовую реализацию [PassiveExpiringMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html) из [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/)